# making a variable string a function name

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering if there was a way to make a var value a function. I'm currently working on a project that makes scripts and runs the code, but when all the function names are the same instead of the two scripts running independent code their writing the same code in unison. If you could show me how to do this it would be a huge help! But I'm not exactly sure if its possible. None the less heres some code

```js
var update = setInterval(function(){
  checkDotPop();
  sc();
}, 1);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

totalDots = 2;
aliveDots = 1;
//styling
body.style.border = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";

function checkDotPop(){
  while(aliveDots != totalDots){
    makeDot();
    aliveDots++;
  }
}
function makeDot(){
  var scr = document.createElement("script");
  scr.setAttribute("id", "dot" + totalDots);
  document.body.appendChild(scr);
  var script = document.getElementById("dot" + totalDots);
  script.innerHTML = "var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); var rand1; var rand2; function changeRand(){rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1; rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;} function sc(){ changeRand(); context.fillStyle = 'red'; context.fillRect(rand1, rand2, 10, 10); context.fill();";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It'll say that "sc is not defined" but in the version I have (using notepad) sc is a gobal function and can be called from script to script

Comment: Why dont you create a global function and call it from the created scripts?

Comment: Because sc is undefined. I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Why are you putting code into strings in the first place? What is higher level objective here?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to create a new "bot" on the canvas with its own independ functions so it can move around and stuff like that. If you have any sources for me to look at that'll be very helpful!

Comment: Use an object constructor for each and within constructor and/or prototype assign methods for each

Answer (score 0):

You where missing a closing bracket for your sc function.

```js
var update = setInterval(function(){
  checkDotPop();
  sc();
}, 1);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

totalDots = 2;
aliveDots = 1;
//styling
body.style.border = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";

function checkDotPop(){
  while(aliveDots != totalDots){
    makeDot();
    aliveDots++;
  }
}
function makeDot(){
  var scr = document.createElement("script");
  scr.setAttribute("id", "dot" + totalDots);
  document.body.appendChild(scr);
  var script = document.getElementById("dot" + totalDots);
  script.innerHTML = "var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); var rand1; var rand2; function changeRand(){rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1; rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;} function sc(){ changeRand(); context.fillStyle = 'red'; context.fillRect(rand1, rand2, 10, 10); context.fill();}";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px"/>
</body>
</html>
```